# Right align text in Select Dropdown without arrow moving

Tags: html, css, right-to-left

I would like to right-align the text within a select box, but when I add:

```
dir="rtl"
```

to the select, the default drop-down arrow moves to the left in Firefox while staying on the right in Chrome:

http://jsfiddle.net/6dts82hL/

I would like to keep the arrow by default to the right, while the text aligns right in all browsers because I will be using CSS to modify this arrow using this method:

http://bavotasan.com/2011/style-select-box-using-only-css/

Your help is much appreciated!

Comment: i dont think you can unless you use something like select2

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using the select2 library, as mentioned by  Daniel A. White. It did exactly what I needed!